# Eclipse how to directly show a list of available functions

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse has a feature in which you write a classname followed by a dot, and a list of available public functions appears. But what if I want to see the functions of the class I am currently in? 
The only solution I know is to write `this.`, select the function from the appearing list, and delete the `this.`.

Is there any way to show the popup menu without writing `this.`, a hotkey perhaps?

Comment: I don't see any reason for why you delete `this.`. Using `methodName();` or `this.methodName();` is the same thing, if `methodName` is a non-static method in your class.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107409/how-to-view-a-objects-methods-in-the-sidebar-in-eclipse explains how to show the list as a sidebar

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What you are referring to is called code completion and can be accessed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Space</kbd> in Eclipse. This will list all variables, fields, methods, classes that is applicable in the current context.

Also, there is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> in Eclipse, which will give you a list of all the available methods in the current class.

Comment: `cmd + o` on Mac

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is press the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>spacebar</kbd> keys.

Answer (score 1):

you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

you can see all methods available in a class

If  you just want to jump from one member to the next (or previous), you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>, respectively.)

Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>