# How to view a object's methods in the sidebar in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, oop, methods

I know in eclipse there is a way to view a object's methods in the sidebar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are referring to the `Outline` view.

[image]

It should be displayed by default in the Java perspective (which I assume you are using), but if you don't see it, you can display it from `Window->Show View->Outline`.

Comment: There is a outline tab for me but it does not show me the methods instead in outline it says: game (the package) than App (the class) than main(String[]): void I don't see the list of methods.

Comment: @user3847117 This view shows you the methods of the class in the file that is currently in focus. Looks like your `App` class is currently in focus, and therefore it shows you the methods of that class (such as `main`).

Comment: how to I remove my App class from focus?

Comment: @user3847117 You open another class

Comment: I have a Card class with 2 variables and when I put my insert on the String keyword it just shows me where it is located in the game package. All my classes are doing this

Comment: @user3847117 The only way for you to see the String class in the Outline tab is by openning the String class (press F3 when pointing to the String keyword).

Comment: alt+shift+q and then O :)